# Samba on OS X 10.6.4

Tags: mac-osx, samba

I just updated from 10.6.3 to 10.6.4, and now my Samba shares won't mount and won't allow access into the directories. In the logs, I've started to get the following errors, any idea what might have gone wrong?

```
2010/06/25 15:54:27, 0, pid=13848] /SourceCache/samba/samba-235.4/samba/source/passdb/secrets.c:secrets_fetch_domain_sid(150)
  secrets_fetch_domain_sid:opendirectory_query_domain_sid gave -14136 [eDSRecordNotFound]
[2010/06/25 15:54:27, 0, pid=13850] /SourceCache/samba/samba-235.4/samba/source/lib/opendirectory.c:get_opendirectory_authenticator(247)
  failed to read DomainAdmin credentials, err=67 fd=19 errno=34
[2010/06/25 15:54:27, 1, pid=13850] /SourceCache/samba/samba-235.4/samba/source/smbd/service.c:make_connection_snum(1092)
  winsrv (10.0.0.8) connect to service Dates initially as user johnd (uid=1028, gid=20) (pid 13850)
[2010/06/25 15:54:42, 1, pid=13850] /SourceCache/samba/samba-235.4/samba/source/smbd/service.c:close_cnum(1289)
  winsrv (10.0.0.8) closed connection to service Dates
[2010/06/25 15:54:44, 0, pid=13850] /SourceCache/samba/samba-235.4/samba/source/passdb/pdb_odsam.c:odssam_getsampwnam(1576)
  opendirectory_sam_searchname gave -14136 [eDSRecordNotFound]: no dsRecTypeStandard:Users record for account 'Administrator'
[2010/06/25 15:54:48, 0, pid=13850] /SourceCache/samba/samba-235.4/samba/source/lib/opendirectory.c:get_opendirectory_authenticator(247)
  failed to read DomainAdmin credentials, err=67 fd=28 errno=34
[2010/06/25 15:54:48, 1, pid=13850] /SourceCache/samba/samba-235.4/samba/source/smbd/service.c:make_connection_snum(1092)
  winsrv (10.0.0.8) connect to service Dates initially as user johnd (uid=1028, gid=20) (pid 13850)
```

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 1):

All my shares were based on symlinks, and this default behaviour was changed in 10.6.4, see here: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=11693384   The errors reported above had little/nothing to do with the problem it seems